# Unable to reference the minified version of jquery inside my bundle

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code inside my App_start folder In my asp.net mvc web application:-

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

But when I modified the above to reference to the minified version of jquery as follow (by adding .min),

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js"));
```

I got errors on the scripts that depends on jquery, and all the error mentioned that the application need to run jquery script.so can anyone adivce how i can refernece the min version of jQuery inside my bundles ?

Comment: Does the jquery min file actually exist in ~/Scripts/ ?

Comment: You cannot reference the `.min` files in your bundle. When you set `compilation debug="false"` in your web config then MVC will automatically use the `.min` version.

Comment: @AaronPalmer yes it is there ..

Comment: @nemesv currently i have the folloiwng inside my web config <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"> . so should i chnage the compilation degug to false ???

Comment: @johnG yes, if you change `debug="false"` it will automatically use the `.min` if exists if no `.min` exists the framework will automatically minify the referenced JavaScript files.

Comment: so u mean that the bundling effect will not have any effect unless i chnage it to false ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices here

1) Add EnableOptimizations is true in RegisterBundles method.

```
 BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

2) Change debug attribute in the compilation Element in the Web.config file to false

```
   <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

The .min version of files will only be used when the debug attribute is false. EnableOptimizations overrides the debug attribute in the compilation Element in the Web.config file

Comment: but in my case i have the degug = true , and when i deploy my application on IIS , then all the scripts and css will be downloaded as bundles, i checked this by viewing the Page source. so i am not sure why i have to chnage the debug to false ?

Comment: The recommended bundle configuration is to only include non-minified .css and .js files, the .min version will be automatically selected if it exists in release builds, i.e. <compilation debug="false">in your Web.config. Also when you deploy your application, it's better to set debug attribute is false. If you don't want to use the debug attribute, you can add EnableOptimizations in your RegisterBundles method.